# Why am I getting RuntimeError while using threading.Thread()?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, concurrency, aiohttp

today is another question day. I am doing requests in python, and I am trying to speed things up. if you recall, I already asked a question about this. Today i have finished that code, and move on to face a similar problem.

Running this code produces a `RuntimeError`. It says:

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'

I don't know why I am getting this error, since I am using threading.Thread() instead of asyncio. Why is it asking for an event loop?

````
def func(mininum, maximum=None):
    if maximum == None:
        maximum = mininum
    import asyncio
    import aiohttp
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    async def find_account(i_d, session):
        try:
            async with session.get(f'https://web.roblox.com/users/{i_d}/profile') as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    r = await response.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
                    stuff = list(soup.find_all('h2'))
                    stuff = stuff[0]
                    stuff = list(stuff)
                    stuff = stuff[0]

                    print(f'{i_d} is done')
                    return str(stuff) + ' ID: {id}'.format(id=i_d)

                else:
                    return 'None'
        except aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError:
            await find_account(i_d, session)
        except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
            await find_account(i_d, session)


    async def id_range(minimum, maximum):
        tasks = []
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for i in range(minimum, maximum + 1):
                tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(find_account(i_d=i, session=session)))

            return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return event_loop.run_until_complete(id_range(mininum, maximum))








import threading

all = []

p1 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(1,1000)).start()
p2 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(1001,2000)).start()

p1 : threading.Thread
p2 : threading.Thread
p1.join()
p2.join()```


#Comment if you need more traceback.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `async`/`await` keywords when using threading.
Instead, the OS will decide automatically when to switch threads.

Comment: So...i have to use asyncio to make asyncio run faster?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Asyncio and Threading are two different solutions to the problem of parallelizing I/O. You should either be using asyncio or using threading, but not both.

Comment: Thank you Dennis for the awesome help. +20 respect